# Appium Launcher in AppiumGUI

Tags: java, ios, mobile-safari, appium

Can somebody tell me does Appium GUI must have a safari launcher? If not, how i can add this launcher to appium?
I tried to add it. I have tried to compile project from github (https://github.com/budhash/SafariLauncher) and put compiled archive to appium.
When I try to use it - safari was launched, but I had the error, that launcher can't find the button. 
What I need do?

Thanks & regards

**Console log**

```
error: Error. Could not find button to launch Safari. Make sure you are using the latest version of SafariLauncher that appium is using

info: [debug] Error: Error. Could not find button to launch Safari. Make sure you are using the latest version of SafariLauncher that appium is using
at [object Object]. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/safari.js:70:17)
at [object Object]. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/common.js:77:12)
at [object Object].iOSController.handleFindCb (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios-controller.js:313:5)
at [object Object]. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios-controller.js:138:14)
at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:798:43)
at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16
at [object Object].exports.respond (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/common.js:28:9)
at [object Object]. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios.js:1498:18)
at getResultAndSendNext (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-uiauto/lib/command-proxy.js:146:20)
at Socket. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-uiauto/lib/command-proxy.js:88:7)
at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
at streamreadable.js:908:16
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

**My java code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DesiredCapabilities safari = new DesiredCapabilities();
        safari.setCapability("browser", "Safari");
        safari.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        safari.setCapability("deviceName", "iPod asolovei");
        AppiumDriver driver = null;

        System.out.println("Before connect to server");

        try {
            driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://192.168.10.42:4723/wd/hub"), safari);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("After connect to server");

        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking like some problem with provision profile .
Visit here https://discuss.appium.io/t/error-installing-safari-launcher-on-real-device-appium-v1-3-7/3793

This thread have same solution .

Answer (score 1):

Update appium to the latest version, this was a bug with Appium 1.4.13. This issue has been resolved in the later versions. 
please follow the below steps to install safari launcher

https://discuss.appium.io/t/error-installing-safari-launcher-on-real-device-appium-v1-3-7/3793